# Having Runtime Error while making a Radar Chart with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, radar-chart

I am trying to make an radar chart to look at the characteristics of the clusters formed by KMeans. The chart was plotting, but when I changed the variables I want to plot, it throws a run time error with incomplete radarchart. I am using the following code:

```
    def _scale_data(data, ranges):
    (x1, x2) = ranges[0]
    d = data[0]
    return [(d - y1) / (y2 - y1) * (x2 - x1) + x1 for d, (y1, y2) in zip(data, ranges)]

class RadarChart():
    def __init__(self, fig, location, sizes, variables, ranges, n_ordinate_levels = 6):

        angles = np.arange(0, 360, 360./len(variables))

        ix, iy = location[:] ; size_x, size_y = sizes[:]

        axes = [fig.add_axes([ix, iy, size_x, size_y], polar = True, 
        label = "axes{}".format(i)) for i in range(len(variables))]

        _, text = axes[0].set_thetagrids(angles, labels = variables)

        for txt, angle in zip(text, angles):
            if angle > -1 and angle < 181:
                txt.set_rotation(angle - 90)
            else:
                txt.set_rotation(angle - 270)

        for ax in axes[1:]:
            ax.patch.set_visible(False)
            ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
            ax.grid("off")

        for i, ax in enumerate(axes):
            grid = np.linspace(*ranges[i],num = n_ordinate_levels)
            grid_label = [""]+["{:.0f}".format(x) for x in grid[1:-1]]
            ax.set_rgrids(grid, labels = grid_label, angle = angles[i])
            ax.set_ylim(*ranges[i])

        self.angle = np.deg2rad(np.r_[angles, angles[0]])
        self.ranges = ranges
        self.ax = axes[0]

    def plot(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.plot(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)

    def fill(self, data, *args, **kw):
        sdata = _scale_data(data, self.ranges)
        self.ax.fill(self.angle, np.r_[sdata, sdata[0]], *args, **kw)

    def legend(self, *args, **kw):
        self.ax.legend(*args, **kw)

    def title(self, title, *args, **kw):
        self.ax.text(0.9, 1, title, transform = self.ax.transAxes, *args, **kw)


#Plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,16))

attributes = ['total_disabled', 'average_payment_amount', 'avg_days_btwn_payments', 'days_since_1st_transaction','days_since_last_transaction','amount_pending']
ranges = [[0.01, 1000], [0.01, 10000], [0.01, 50], [0.01, 1000], [0.01, 500], [0.01, 10000]]
index  = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7]

n_groups = n_clusters ; i_cols = 3
i_rows = n_groups//i_cols
size_x, size_y = (1/i_cols), (1/i_rows)

for ind in range(n_clusters):
    ix = ind%3 ; iy = i_rows - ind//3
    pos_x = ix*(size_x + 0.05) ; pos_y = iy*(size_y + 0.05)            
    location = [pos_x, pos_y]  ; sizes = [size_x, size_y] 
    #______________________________________________________
    data = np.array(clustered_df.loc[index[ind], attributes])    
    radar = RadarChart(fig, location, sizes, attributes, ranges)
    radar.plot(data, color = 'b', linewidth=2.0)
    radar.fill(data, alpha = 0.2, color = 'b')
    radar.title(title = 'cluster nº{}'.format(index[ind]), color = 'r')
    ind += 1
```

And it gives the following error:
C:\Users\arindam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:1020: FutureWarning:

Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise
KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative.

See the documentation here:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike

C:\Users\arindam\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\projections\polar.py:65: RuntimeWarning:

invalid value encountered in less

I hope someone can help me out with this. Thanks in advance.